# How to provide different set of properties to the different executions of a plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using `maven-assembly-plugin` to assemble different artifacts as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration-staging</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration-production</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In `assembly.xml`, I enabled template filtering:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
```

This works great. For example, if I enter `${name}` in one of the resources to be assembled, this is replaced by the name of the project. I could also define properties in `pom.xml`, which will be replaced by the plugin.

Now, I would like to have different properties for each execution of `maven-assembly-plugin`. For example, I would like to introduce a `${url}` which holds the URL to be used on the target environment (`staging` and `production` in the example above).

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Have you tried to put the `<configuration>` into the `<execution>`?

Comment: It's not about the `assembly.xml`. This is shared between the different executions; hence I decided to define that outside the `<configuration`>. It's about having different property sets for the different executions. For execution `configuration-staging` I want to resolve a different `{$url}` value than for `configuration-production`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, it is possible to pass different properties for each execution in the `maven-assembly-plugin` as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration-staging</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>staging</finalName>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>src/main/assembly/staging.properties</filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration-production</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>production</finalName>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>src/main/assembly/production.properties</filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Although this does not answer the generic question, it answers the question specifically for `maven-assembly-plugin`.

More can be found on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html.

Comment: And what to do if variables are not interpolated? In my case every property in the <filter> file is not used by the Interpolator.

Comment: It seems that it works only for properties declared in the <files> section, so for the output context. It has no effect for the assembly.xml itself, so if you have some properties you can't use the <filter> in the assembly.xml

Comment: I solved the properties in the assembly.xml file issue by two phase process:

1) filter the template assembly.xml using multiple executions of the maven-resources-plugin (creating multiple output directories, i.e. one for each property file)

2) trigger the maven-assembly-plugin for each generated assembly.xml, i.e. provide multiple descriptors in the configuration

this enables using properties also in the assembly.xml (e.g. for also providing the id that will become the classifier)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the properties Maven plugin

https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/index.html

that allows you read properties from files or URLs.

Comment: How can I link this to the different executions of the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin? Each execution should have a different set of properties.

Comment: You probably have to wrap this into profiles and make two separate runs of Maven. Maven resolves properties pretty early in the run, so you probably cannot change them inside the same lifecycle run.

Comment: Different profiles is a good idea, I'll give it a shot. Hopefully there is way to do this without different profiles, as the introduction of different profiles might give issues in Jenkins.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this ?